# JQuery .load() inside div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This has been driving me nuts! I've searched and tried a bunch of suggestions that seem like they should work, so I must be doing something foolish.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.trigger').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#target').load(link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

and

```
<div id='content'>
This is some stuff that I want left alone.
<a href="testload1.html" class="trigger">Click here</a>
<a href="testload2.html" class="trigger">Click here</a>
</div>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

I'm trying to load the html document "testload1" and "testload2" (which just contain a line of text) into the "target" div.

Instead what happens is the "testload1" page just loads as a normal link would.

edit: more info

I tried the suggested changes below with no difference. This leads me to think there is something wrong with the rest of the file, so here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.trigger').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#target').load(link);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
This is some stuff that I want left alone.
<a href="testload1.html" class="trigger">Click here</a>
<a href="testload2.html" class="trigger">Click here</a>
</div>
<div id="target">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any reason this shouldn't work?

Comment: Your code looks fine... how is the `content` element loaded? is it created dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you just need to prevent the default action when you click a link or check the url.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var link = $(this).attr("href");
         $('#target').load(link);
      });
});
```

[Also there's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/syE7s/)

Comment: @Musa - that appears to be the intention, but the cited behavior suggests that it isn't doing the job.

Comment: @ScottHunter or the fact that `$('.trigger')` does not get the elements to register the event because it is dynamically created

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('.trigger').click(function(){
      var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $('#target').load( link + ' body' );
      return false;
  });
});
```

and it's better to have a basic html structure in target files like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Content
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your links are created dynamically, use event delegation with `.on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.trigger', function () {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#target').load(link);
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation