# Load external HTML page into DIV on new page when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to setup a function which allows the following:

1. I have one page with multiple links ('page1.html')
2. When I select any of these links, it opens up ('page2.html'), which contains a DIV
3. Depending on the link selected, the DIV displays an external HTML file.

So in summary `page2.html` will remain the same but the links on `page1.html` will determine which external HTML file (`1.html` to `10.html`, for example) is loaded into the DIV on `page2.html`

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible.

Comment: Page1 redirects to Page2 which should know which link was clicked on page1 and load the corresponding page into the div?

Comment: He is searching for something like this: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery) Pass number 1-10 to page2 and then read the argument and load partial with jquery

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking to do.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005649/jquery-load-inside-div

Comment: Thanks chaps, I'll have a look at the links provided