# jquery load base on href with the selector only

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, load, href

newbie here.

I just learned how to grab a content from a specific div that was in another page (same domain) and load it in the current page.

Now I'm trying to get jquery code to grab a content from a specific div id based on the url link to the page. Here's a code I currently have, similar from this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005649/jquery-load-inside-div).

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    $("#div").load($(this).attr("href")); /* how to only load the #div id, based on the <a>'s href link to the page? */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

pass in the selector of element you want to load content of, like:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    var url  = $(this).attr("href") + " #yourDivID";
    $("#div").load(url);
});
```